# connecting to database fails with laravel mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, ssh, forge, heidisql

```
my project is hosted in forge (digital ocean) laravel 5.1
```

I can connect (ssh) normally with putty using ssh file key by taping only the username but I fail when I try to connect to database with `heidisql` with the same ssh key file , I used to connect normally but the last month after a payment problem i always fail and i Get

`Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

and in the webpage I get

```
[PDOException]       SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

any solution please

Answer (score 0):

solved by sudo service mysql restart